# OnRowSelect Set State in JS React - Allowing Filtered Route Selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to pass an argument, setting 'fooId' to a temporary state, allowing to me set the default filter for the user to all 'fooId's within a react-data-grid when they clicked on the row(a cell value used for filtering). I thought I could make a function to set the state and pass that through the filter. The backend and supporting Sagas, Reducer, ect are built to support passing data. I just need to figure out this change in default filtering to set the filter to slice 'filteredData'. Hope it makes sense...Please see applicable code below, thanks:

```
function FooBar({fooBar, filteredData, fooBarSearch, toDate, fromDate, searchText, foobar}) {

let filterData = fooBar.slice();
function onRowClickFoo(event) { let fooBarId = set.state.fooId return 
selectRoute('bar/whee/' + fooId); }

return (

<div>
    <Grid fluid>
        <Row className={styles.fooPage}>
            <Col xs={12} md={3}>
                <AutoComplete
                    floatingLabelText="Search Foo"
                    filter={AutoComplete.caseInsensitiveFilter}
                    openOnFocus={true}
                    dataSource={foobar}
                    searchText={searchText}
                    dataSourceConfig={{text: 'fooId', value: 'fooId'}}
                    onUpdateInput={searchOnUpdateHandler}
                    onNewRequest={searchOnNewRequest}
                    maxSearchResults={8}
                />
            </Col>
            <Col xs={12} md={3}>
                <DatePicker
                    onChange={fromDateOnChangeHandler}
                    floatingLabelText="Filter Start Date"
                    autoOk={true}
                    value={fromDate}
                    mode="landscape"
                    firstDayOfWeek={0}
                    shouldDisableDate={disableStartDays}
                />
            </Col>
            <Col xs={12} md={3}>
                <DatePicker
                    onChange={toDateOnChangeHandler}
                    floatingLabelText="Filter End Date"
                    autoOk={true}
                    value={toDate}
                    mode="landscape"
                    firstDayOfWeek={0}
                    shouldDisableDate={disableEndDays}
                />
            </Col>
            <Col xs={12} md={3} className={styles.resetButton}>
                <RaisedButton
                    label="Reset"
                    secondary={true}
                    onTouchTap={handleResetFilter}
                />
            </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Col xs={12}>
                <fooBarGrid className={styles.fooBarGrid}
                               columnHeaders={columnHeaders}
                               rows={filteredData}
                               enableRowSelect={true}
                               onRowSelect={onRowClickFoo}
                />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to understand what you're going for, but ... I think I understand.

If you want to use component-local state, you'll have to either use a Component *class*, or use an HOC to store the state for you (the `recompose` package has `withState`, which I find very very useful).

example; vanilla React

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    filter: null
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.props
    const { filter } = this.state

    const mData = data.filter((dataRow) => dataRow.id === filter)

    return (
      /* use mData */
    )
  }
}
```

using `recompose`

```
const Foo = ({ data, filter, setFilter }) => {
  const mData = data.filter((dataRow) => dataRow.id === filter)
  const onRowClick = (event) => setFilter(/* whatever you want to filter to */)

  return (
    /* use mData */
  )
}

export default withState("filter", "setFilter", null)(Foo)
```